# Api Platform SearchFilter with User Roles

Tags: postgresql, symfony, api-platform.com

Im trying to use Api-platform SearchFilter with exact value of a **json** PostgreSQL column `roles` inside `User.php` entity:

```
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['roles' => 'exact']

#[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
public ?array $roles = [];
```

- What is the correct format to write the url from frontend to avoid this error ?

> An exception occurred while executing a query :SQLSTATE[42883]:
> Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json =
> unknown\nLINE 1: ...3 || '%' AND u0_.date_of_birth = $4 AND u0_.roles
> = $5 ORDER... ^\nHINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.\n

- I tried a lot of things even encoding the url parameters but nothing works for me with json like: `https://.../users&roles='["ROLE_ADMIN"]'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I fixed the issue using `simple_array`:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'simple_array')]
public ?array $roles = [];
```

Important,according to documentation:

> IMPORTANT Only use this type if you are sure that your values cannot contain a ",".

This fits well with `roles`, but be careful when using `simple_array` with other columns.

Update: It seems API Platforms it's not able to perform search in json arrays. https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2274